# java fx 8 can it be a alternative to flex

Tags: java, html, apache-flex, audio, javafx

We have a flex part in a web application which is doing a lot of heavy tasks with audio, like

1. running multiple audio,
2. play pause stop and recoding functionality,
3. working with sound wave form and
4. some manipulations with sound's byte array.

**Problem**: Facing latency issues as it get's heavier with more number of audio tracks added and also single-thread achitechture is a concern.

I searched a lot but haven't got good resources of java fx 8. What I am concerned about is whether java fx 8, released in March 14, is stable enough to start with and whether I will get all the features that flex has been giving and also, whether html 5 can also be considered as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I might not have empirical data to back it up, experience says that these are intensive operations regardless of the front-end technology used. This is primarily due to the fact that you are relying on the user's cpu cores to do this work. This isn't to say that one is better than the other - it's more that the ROI for a re-write probably will not pay off like you expect it to, based purely on performance reasons.

As for single-threadedness - the Flash Player Platform supports workers, which actually sounds like a good candidate for your application as it can more easily be divided into discrete cores.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html

Comment: The problem is some where the same down the line as lot of core processing plus graphic processing is going on.Worker thread can not be an option at the moment as it's in 4.6 onwards version and we are using the earlier version.What I was looking for that how better java fx8 can forward these task to the cpu if it can as compare to flex.As I searched and found some content related to prism that if internal graphic is not that strong then FX use it's own processing for rendering graphic with the help of prism, but haven't found any implementation story.